# When building a Word macro, how do I find a specific text item in a table using Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, word-2007

I am trying to find all dashes that are alone in table cells and center them. What i have built below thus far will center all dashes in the document. How can I encapsulate this to center only the dashes in cells by themselves?

```
 Sub Macro9()
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
   With Selection.Find.Replacement.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
   End With

   With Selection.Find
    .Text = "-"
    .Replacement.Text = "-"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to restrict your searches to only a single dash in a single cell, you're better off only checking cell contents. Otherwise if you use `.Find` in the range of a table, you'll have to check all sorts of special cases to make sure the "found" dash is all alone in the cell. I think this works pretty efficiently:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro9()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim tCell As Cell
    Dim r, c As Integer
    Dim cellContents As String

    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
                Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, c)
                '--- trim the cell delimiter off the end, then whitespace
                cellContents = Left(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 2)
                cellContents = Trim(cellContents)
                If cellContents = "-" Then
                    tCell.Select
                    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    Next tbl

End Sub
```

Comment: what are your thoughts on the answer I came up with?

Answer (score 0):

@PeterT  what are you thoughts on this? (a collegue and I pulled it together)

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim CurrentText As Range
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "-"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Do While Selection.Find.Execute

If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    Set CurrentText = Selection.Cells(1).Range
    CurrentText.End = CurrentText.End - 1
    If (CurrentText.Text = "-") And Not (Selection.Information(wdAlignParagraphCenter)) Then
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    End If
  End If
Loop      
End Sub
```

Comment: While I've used `Find` successfully in the past, I admit to not having high-level mojo for it. Your macro certainly works well and does the job -- I now have learned about `Selection.Information` which will be very helpful in the future. If you'd like to unselect the last dash in the document, add the line `Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd`. Good work.